# Cannot remove subset 1 data from subset 2 in Python plotly graph

Tags: python

The current Python script correctly generates an html chart with candlestick data in the top pane (subset 1) and volume data in the bottom pane (subset 2). The issue is that the bottom pane adds subset 1 separately on the chart when it should include only the volume data.

Here is the current script:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.subplots as sp  
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import webbrowser  

# Create a candlestick chart with volume bars using csv data

# Suppress the SettingWithCopyWarning
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

# Read the CSV file and parse the 'Date' column as datetime
df = pd.read_csv('/home/lpc123/Downloads/result.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])

# Filter the DataFrame for the desired date range
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2023-03-01')  # Replace with your desired start date
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2023-07-28')    # Replace with your desired end date
df_subset = df.loc[(df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date)]


# Create a subplot grid with two rows (1 row for candlestick chart, 1 row for volume bars)
fig = sp.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.1,
                       row_heights=[0.75, 0.25])  # Set the row heights proportionally

# Add candlestick trace to the first row (row=1), specifying the primary y-axis (yaxis="y")
fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=df_subset['Date'],
                             open=df_subset['Open'],
                             high=df_subset['High'],
                             low=df_subset['Low'],
                             close=df_subset['Close'],
                             name='Candlestick',
                             showlegend=False), row=1, col=1, secondary_y=False)

# Add volume bars trace to the second row (row=2)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df_subset['Date'],
                     y=df_subset['Volume'],
                     name='Volume',
                     showlegend=False), row=2, col=1)

# Set the dimensions of the plot (adjust these values as needed)
fig.update_layout(height=900, width=1500, title_text="Portfolio Chart",
                  yaxis_title="Price", yaxis2_title="Volume")

# Specify the rangebreaks to exclude weekends (Saturdays and Sundays)
fig.update_xaxes(rangebreaks=[
    {'pattern': 'day of week', 'bounds': [6, 1]}  # Excludes Saturdays and Sundays
])

output_file = '/home/lpc123/Downloads/result.jpeg'

# Save the figure as a JPEG image using the write_image method
fig.write_image(output_file, format="jpeg")

# Automatically open the file in the default browser
webbrowser.open(output_file)
```

To solve, I tried to set the y-axis domain for each subplot explicitly, i.e. using the fig.update_yaxes() method to set the y-axis domain for each subplot. The domain parameter takes a list with two values representing the start and end points of the y-axis range for each subplot. By setting domain=[0.55, 1] for the candlestick chart and domain=[0, 0.45] for the volume bars, we ensure that they are placed separately within their respective subplots.

That did not work either. Advice is appreciated.

Comment: FYI, Python is version 3.11 and Plotly is 5.15.0.